# npm script fails when using **/* in path

Tags: npm

Running `shasum --algorithm 256 ./{bin,lib}/**/* > SHA256SUM` in terminal works as expected but running `npm run checkum` results in empty `SHA256SUM`.

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "checksum": "shasum --algorithm 256 ./{bin,lib}/**/* > SHA256SUM"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it work inside a shell script?

Comment: @tadman Interesting… no